# Light switch outlet questions

Tags: electrical, light, dimmer-switch

I am trying to replace a old dimmer that stopped working and when I took off the light switch I could not back trace my work. The light switch it use to have was a dimmer. I am trying to connect single switches to control the light. I am a new home owner and just trying to figure this out thanks for the help [image]

Comment: How many switches were in this box? How many (if any) are 3-way switches (a switch here and a switch someplace can both be used to turn a light on/off)?

Comment: One was a dummy switch nothing connected to it. Another a single pole switch and the third one a dimmer (fan and light)

Comment: Fans are not normally put on dimmers, so that raises some questions. By "nothing connected", do you mean "no wires connected to that switch" or "the switch was connected to wires but you never found anything that turned on/off when you flipped the switch"?

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact no, but fans are often put on 3-position rotary controllers for selecting one of 3 speeds (plus off). They _look_ just like the old-skool rotary dimmers, so it's entirely reasonable for people to _call_ them "dimmers". I've got these types of switches on every one of the 7 ceiling fans in my house.

Comment: Holy smoke!  Never, ever dismantle a thing like this and splay the wires all out like that.  The way information is passed on about "which wires do what" is by how things are wired *already*.  All we know now is all the whites are neutral and the /2 black is probably supply hot.  Which is a start, at least.